# Java Eclipse output to csv file

Tags: java, eclipse, csv, console, output

I'd like to redirect my Java Eclipse's console output to a CSV file.
I know how to do that for a TXT file (Run Configurations-Common-etc.), but I can't find how to get a CSV file.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for this in Eclipse.

Console output is generally not in a format suitable for a CSV file. It is up to you to add code to your program to generate the correct format for CSV.

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if it helps, but csv is basicly txt. You can separate your output by ";" in compile time, output it to txt and then just save it like CSV.

Comment: yes, in the meantime I wait for a solution I'm trying something like that. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `System.out.println()` but define a `PrintStream` that you use somewhere, so it becomes `myOut.println()`.

Or better, use a logger-library for it, for example `log4j`, or even a facade: `slf4j`

Answer (score 0):

I think whatever you are printing on the console, you can just use one of these solutions to write it in CSV format and that's pretty much it.

1> Simple Solution: If you are sure the CSV files doesn’t contain “separator or double-quotes”, just use the standard split() to parse the CSV file.

2> Advance Solution: This solution will solve the field containing “separator or double-quotes” issue, and also support the custom separator and custom enclosed field. Review the following CSV parsing example and also the JUnit test cases to understand how it works.

3> OpenCSV Example: If you are not comfortable with above simple and advance solution, try using third party CSV library – OpenCSV.

https://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-and-parse-csv-file-in-java/